# Copy link to clipboard, paste a hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have multiple checkboxes beside files and there is 1 share button, on checking of multiple checkboxes and then click on share button I want to copy the download URL for those files. I am able to copy the download URL's for them and I am also able to paste them in notepad/webmail.

But my problem is I should only be able paste the file name which will be an hyperlink and on click of that file name a link will pop-up.

How can I copy only the file name and paste it as a hyperlink on notepad/clipboard. Please guide me. Below is my code.

```
shareDoc(){
    const textArea1 = document.createElement('textArea');
    this.docs.forEach(docs => {
    const downloadURL = this.service.getURL(id);
    const link = '<a href="'+downloadURL+'">'+doc.name+'</a></br>';
    textArea1.value = textArea1.value+link;
  });
  document.body.appendChild(textArea1);
  textArea1.focus();
  textArea1.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(textArea1);
}
```

On pasting this to a clipboard/webmail, I am getting this

```
<a href="http://downloadlink1.com">File1</a><br/><a href="http://downloadlink2.com">File2</a><br/><a href="http://downloadlink3.com">File3</a>
```

but it should appear as hyperlinks, as below

[File1](http://downloadlink1.com)
[File2](http://downloadlink2.com)
[File3](http://downloadlink3.com)

please guide me achieve this.

PS: I work on angular 4 and primeNG 5

Answer (score 0):

You can't chose how the link will be pasted for the user, for the simple reason that you can't know what the user will do with it.

For instance, let's say I take your link and paste it here, on SOF : the syntax would be

```
[File1](http://downloadlink1.com)
```

And now, i want to share it with a buddy of mine, through mail : the syntax would be

```
<a href="http://downloadlink1.com">File1</a>
```

And even with this syntax, depending on the client I use and how I paste it, it could simply display the raw text instead of the link.

As you can see, I can't do both, I can chose only one solution.

What I would recommend is thay you only copy the link `http://downloadlink1.com`, and let the user decide what he wants to do with it.